# How do i return streaming data as Httpresponse in django, i'm working with tweepy and django?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on something that needs streaming data to be returned as response to the browser,but httpresponse fails to do it.

Comment: Where's your relevant code? What's the error? What's the actual question (assuming that you have a question)?

Comment: @timgeb people familiar with django knows what is http response and how it works in django. Stop criticising and show some respect

Answer (score 1):

You should use [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse) instead of normal HTTP Response.

Comment: It's better to handover streaming to nginx. If not possible, you should accept the cost.